# Can I insert ACF repeater fields into MaxMegaMenu via JS?

Tags: javascript, advanced-custom-fields, repeater, megamenu

I have to add a Slick slider with ACF repeating fields to MaxMegaMenu, unfortunately I don't know how to add such a large piece of code via Javascript (passing js Var?). Has anyone tried to add ACF repeater using Javascript?

My code below
++++++++++++++++

```
<?php if ( have_rows('postgraduate_studies', 'option') ) :
 while( have_rows('postgraduate_studies', 'option') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <?php the_sub_field('sub_field_name', 'option'); ?>
    <div style="background-image: url( <?php the_sub_field('postgraduate_studies_image', 'option'); ?>);"  class="">
      <a href="<?php the_sub_field('postgraduate_studies_link', 'option'); ?>"> 
        <p><?php the_sub_field('postgraduate_studies_text', 'option'); ?></p>
      </a>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You'll probably get better help for this over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Done, Thank you :-)